# how can i give zooming in wpf charting toolkit?

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I need to give the zooming in wpf toolkit chart.

I have two options to acheive this one way is via using UserControl which I dont feel is good as it will require a lot of effort. Second, I tried to extend Chart and LineSeries classes of it but these are sealed classes.

Any idea how can I achieve this functionality.
Thanks in advance.

D J

Answer (score 1):

when i want to do zooming with wpf a simply use ScaleTransform. does this work for you to?

```
  <Slider x:Name="zoomer" Width="100" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Zoomer, Mode=TwoWay}"  Minimum="0.8" Maximum="2.2" TickFrequency="0.1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />

    <YourChartControl>
        <YourChartControlLayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomer, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomer, Path=Value}"></ScaleTransform>
        </YourChartControlx:Name.LayoutTransform>
     </YourChartControl>
```

Comment: As I need it for charting I cant use this solution. Actually i need to zoom those points which user has selected in selection window. It can be a selected part of chart also.